# How to show given set is dense $G_{\delta}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let X ,Y be Banach Space. A is subset of bounded linear operator between X and Y

Suppose $\sup_{P\in A}||P||=\infty$

Then set $\{x\in X|\sup_{P\in A }||Px||=\infty\}$ is dense $G_{\delta}$ set in X

$G_{\delta}$ are set which is countable intersection of open set.

Can anyone give me some hint to start problem

I do not know how to start ANy Help will be appreciated

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are trying to show

Comment: Should the 3rd line be "Show that the set ... "?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\{x: \sup \|Px\| >n\}$. If $x$ is an element of this set then there exists $P_0 \in  A$ such that $\|P_0x\| >n$. If $\|y-x\| <\frac {n-\|P_0x\|} {\|P_0\|}$ then $\|P_0y\|\geq \|P_0x\|-\|P_0\| \|x-y\|>n$. Thus $\{x: \sup \|Px\| >n\}$ is open for each $n$ and its intersection  over $n$, which is the given set, is  a $G_{\delta}$.

To prove that the set is dense we can use UBP: Suppose the set is not dense. Then there exists some open ball $B(x,r)$ which is disjoint from this set. Thus $\sup \|Py\| <\infty$ whenever $\|y-x\|<r$. In particular we have $\sup_A \|Px\| <\infty$ and this gives $\sup \|Pz\| <\infty$ whenver $\|z\|<r$. But then $\sup \|Pz\| <\infty$ for any $z$. By UBP we get $\sup_A \|P\|<\infty$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir . I have one doubt why sup ||Pz||<infty for any z?

Comment: @MathLover Just use scaling: for any $z$ there exists $c$ such that $\|cz\| <r$. This gives $\sup _A\|P(cz)\|<\infty$ and hence  $\sup _A\|P(z)\|<\infty$